# Ubuntu 18.04 new second IP not working

Tags: networking, 18.04

On my VPS i have 2 ip-adresses. Now the hosting company changed my second ip-adress.
I changed the ip-adress in the /etc/netplan/*.yaml to the new one, but the new one does not work, sites not work and can't ping the new IP.
Here my config file:

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
  ens3:
   dhcp4: no
   dhcp6: no
   addresses: [5.157.82.219/23, 185.37.68.40/24]
   gateway4: 5.157.82.1
   nameservers:
   addresses: [109.235.76.162,93.94.226.236,85.158.203.252,85.158.200.76,8.8.8.8]
```

I just replaced the second ip, anyone maybe know why its not working?

---

[image: VPS IP settings]
Here a screenshot from the account page

Comment: Did you do a `sudo netplan --debug generate` and a `sudo netplan apply`? And I just noticed... the second address isn't even on the same subnet. And why is one netmask = 23 and the other = 24?

Comment: Please edit such text as an edit into your original question. It's impossible to read in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Can't edit in the commands..
i will try your settings

Comment: No, you can't edit the comments after 4 minutes. You need to redo the command, copy the output to the clipboard, edit your question, paste the clipboard at the end of your text, select the pasted text, and format it with the {} icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Use copy/paste ALL of the text, to update your .yaml file.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses:
        - 5.157.82.219/23
        - 185.37.68.40/24
      #gateway4: 5.157.82.1 # not used with routes
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 5.157.82.1
          metric: 100
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 185.37.68.1
          metric: 100
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 5.157.86.220
          - 5.157.87.220
          - 5.157.86.221
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

Comment: Same, first IP is working, second not. i don't get it. before the ip change these settings where working.

Comment: Also does not work on DHCP

Comment: @Rick try my new edit. Report back.

Comment: Sorry still not working :( 
I don't get that with the old IP it just workt, new ip, change just the ip in config and its not working. Could it be a fault with the hosting company?

Comment: You need to ask what's the correct gateway for the 2nd address... I guessed it was 185.37.68.1, but if it's different, you'll have to edit in the correct address. OR... is the new address supposed to REPLACE the first address? Did you copy/paste my entire text? What are you actually expecting to work differently with the addition of the 2nd address?

Comment: gateway is correct indeed. My previous Second ip was: 109.235.76.137 that changed to 185.37.68.40. that's all that changed to my VPS.. it should be a simple replace of ip. but seems not as simple.. yes copy/paste all.

Comment: @Rick Any reason why none of your DNS servers are like the ones shown in your VPS settings image? Lets test the 2nd IP by itself. Comment out the first IP, and the first route, generate and apply. Report back. Have you rebooted after a .yaml change?  If it doesn't work, set it all back the way I show, and contact your VPS host provider.

Comment: I just did not update the DNS in the example.. 
I did that before. only use the second ip, and could not connect back to the VPS. all sites down.
Yes i reboot after every change

Edit: all went down again. no connection to vps anymore

Comment: @Rick you lost me. "all sites down" when running on just the new IP? Switching the .yaml file back brought you back up on the first IP, yes? If so, contact your VPS provider, as your new IP doesn't work.

Comment: correct.
I will contact them
Thank you for al the help!
Last question, could you explain the 'routes' never used that

Comment: @Rick since you have two different IP addresses, and each has a different gateway, you can't just use "gateway4: 5.157.82.1" for both... that's why it's commented out now... and we define separate gateways in the routes stanza. See https://netplan.io/examples for more detail. Let me know how you make out, ok?

Comment: i will let you know next weekend

Comment: i reinstalled the whole server. and it was working immediately when i changed the yaml file with the first config i posted in my question..... so changing an ip requires a new server installation.. thats nice.

Comment: @Rick after changing the .yaml file, did you do `sudo netplan --debug generate` and `sudo netplan apply`? The `apply` command actually implements the new config, but some things do require a reboot to take. I know that's more difficult on servers. Your example .yaml file, although it may give you the correct IP's that you desired, it really can't be right, as each IP has a different gateway, and you don't specify that. My .yaml should be more correct, and you may still wish to give it a try.

Comment: Yes applied and reboot after every change.

I will try your .yaml. i read the url you gave me, but still do not understand why the settings are to '0.0.0.0'  and metric 100 is dhcp auto? for what?

Comment: @Rick the metrics are use to prioritize one IP over the other. Right now, they're set the same.