# Help with adding second ip to second interface

Tags: 18.04

I spent all day searching online and I cannot find solution for what I'm trying to do.

Basically I have ESXi Ubuntu VM on OVH and block of IPs. Currently I have 1 IP configured and have web server and its using port 80 and 443 for SSL. Since I need also port 443 for different service I would like to use my spare IP and for that second interface and service. 
I found something that should work  https://askubuntu.com/a/1124533/838787 but I loose connection after reboot and I have to restore netplan yaml in order to get it back online.

Here's the current working netplan yaml file for 1 IP:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
   ens33:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no    
     addresses: ['192.xx.xxx.200/32']
     gateway4: 158.69.xxx.xxx
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
     routes: 
     - to: 158.69.xxx.xxx/32
       via: 192.xx.xxx.200
       scope: link
```

ip addr output showing second ens36 interface

```
root@ubuntu:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:09:97:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.xx.xxx.200/32 scope global ens33
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe09:97xx/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens36: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:02:af:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Here's SS of added second interface in ESXi:
https://prnt.sc/rv4r11